# Sorting Linq results ascending using subselect and then descending

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I am trying to work out a LINQ query to pull items from a List, the List contains a child-nested List - which I need to query for an item, then use the resulting item in my final sort of all records returned the query.

The parent is List(Of MediaItems) - the class structure as follows:

```
MediaItems
 .ID (int)
 .Src (string)
 .Advert (bool)
 .AdOptions As List(Of AdvertOptions)
 .Counter (int)

AdvertOptions class consists of:
 .Age (int)
 .Gender (int)
 .Priority (int)
```

I want to query for any MediaItems that meet the following criteria:

```
.Advert = true
.Age = x (paramter in calling function)
.Gender = y (paramter in calling function)
```

To do this, I am using the following LINQ query: (Age and Gender are the function parameters)

```
Where(Function(s) s.Advert And s.AdOptions.Any(Function(a) a.Gender = Gender And a.Age = Age))
```

I now need to sort the results based on two sorting levels:

AdOptions.Priority (in descending order), then sort by Counter in ascending order

This is my failing attempt:

```
Where(Function(s) s.Advert And s.AdOptions.Any(Function(a) a.Gender = Gender And a.Age = Age)).OrderBy(Function(a) From p1 In a.AdOptions Where p1.Gender = Gender And p1.Age = Age Select p1.Priority).ThenByDescending(Function(s) s.Counter)
```

My attempt is not working, I am getting the following error:

> at least on object must implement IComparable

Can anyone see what needs to be done to achieve my goal?

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reading your code a bit closer, I spotted that you order by AdOptions

I think *this* is what you really want

```
Sub Demo(ByVal gender As Integer, ByVal age As Integer)

    Dim items = New List(Of MediaItem)()

    Dim matching = Function(a) a.Gender = gender And a.Age = age
    Dim ads = items.Where(Function(s) s.Advert And s.AdOptions.Any(matching))

    Dim sorted = ads _
        .OrderBy(Function(a) a.AdOptions.Where(matching).Max(Function(ao) ao.Priority)) _
        .ThenByDescending(Function(s) s.Counter)

    ' if you really wanted a sorted list of AdOptions, you'd write
    Dim optionlist = ads.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Counter) _
       .SelectMany(Function(a) a.AdOptions.Where(matching).OrderBy(Function(ao) ao.Priority))

    ' to combine the two previous options
    Dim adsWithOptions = ads.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Counter) _
       .Select(Function(a) New With { _
                  .Ad = a, _
                  .Options = a.AdOptions.Where(matching) _
                      .OrderBy(Function(ao) ao.Priority) _
            })

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still fairly new to Linq so I'll research these suggestions. If you know of any good examples, I'd love to see them. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ben: replaced my answer with likely what you want. Note, that I now assume that you want to sort by the highest priority of the ad (since it can have multiple AdOptions)

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around your answer (trying to learn quickly). I think you've got it.